# Thus await makes any difference if use before _SecondaryContext.userdata_primary.InsertOneAsync(response); and then savechanges to save data in mongo?

Tags: c#, mongodb, backend, web-deployment

I'm calling an function save() to save data in mongodb database in C#

```
public void Save(class_name response){
 using (var  _SecondaryContext = new MongoDbContext())
 {
   _SecondaryContext.userdata_primary.InsertOneAsync(response);
   _SecondaryContext.SaveChanges();
 } 
}
```

above code works fine without any error it also stores data in my database but not everytime. In some cases data is missing from database, data was not store. I think it's because of InsertOneAysnc which is an Aysnc task, in heavy traffic it doesn't work properly thats what I think.
So I tried making Save() function async and use await on insert before saveChanges

```
public async void Save(class_name response){
 using (var  _SecondaryContext = new MongoDbContext())
 {
   await _SecondaryContext.userdata_primary.InsertOneAsync(response);
   _SecondaryContext.SaveChanges();
 } 
}
```

will it work properly in heavy traffic ? I don't have a way to test it

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your change is correct.
In the first case you were not waiting for the insert to happen before saving the changes, causing it to not be saved.

Regarding traffic it depends on how much volume you're expecting. As for coding principles, await/async are used correctly here.
Your change will not cause extra unnecessary delays, actually it will give faster user experience since the Save function is async.

If users have experienced delays, maybe the number of requests is bigger than the maximum it can be handled from the db server. In this case you have to investigate strategies to scale the db, but this is another topic.

Comment: but using await if I have large data to insert my application will stuck for few sec or min right ? The save function which I'm calling is being called in an API function to save data. I want this entire operation of inserting data to run in background without affecting my user interface will it work that way ? I don't have any way of testing it

Comment: If you call Save() instead of await Save(), then it will run asynchronously. Are you just assuming it will take seconds or do you have an exact case of delay? You are basically inserting here which should be quick.

Comment: Another suggestion: Maybe you don't need to create a new context inside the method. If this method is inside a repository, you can share the context and use dependency injection. This may improve the performance since it doesn't spend time to recreate the context.

Comment: im just assuming

Comment: You don't have to worry about that since it's out of scope and it won't be a side effect of your change. Btw @Stephen Cleary has a good point regarding the use of Task instead of void. If you want to understand when the task is finished, you must use it.

Answer (score 2):

> In some cases data is missing from database, data was not store. I think it's because of InsertOneAysnc which is an Aysnc task, in heavy traffic it doesn't work properly

The code is *starting* the asynchronous task, but it doesn't (asynchronously) wait for it to complete. Losing data is one possible side effect of "fire and forget" asynchronous work like this.

> So I tried making Save() function async and use await on insert before saveChanges

Using `await` is the correct solution, but [using `async void` is not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void). `async void` forces any callers of `Save` to use fire-and-forget, and you're back in the same situation. The proper solution is to use `await` and then make `Save` an `async Task` method. And then you have to use `await` for every place that calls `Save`, and make them `async` methods returning `Task`/`Task<T>`, etc.